# Steam hangs without showing window on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: steam

The "steam" official package from the Ubuntu app store doesn't work, giving errors about missing .tar.xz files.

The "steam" installer from the steampowered.com site used to work on Ubuntu 17.04 just fine. However, today, it doesn't start, but just hangs.
Running it from the command line, I see this:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 17.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
```

and then nothing. The process just sits there, and doesn't show any window or anything.

The following processes are running:

```
[18:25] jwatte@ripper:~/Downloads$ ps alx | grep [s]team
0  1000  37467  37199  20   0  12732  3288 wait   S+   pts/1      0:00 bash /usr/bin/steam
0  1000  37477  37467  20   0  12932  3492 wait   S+   pts/1      0:00 bash /home/jwatte/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh
0  1000  37591  37477  20   0  51856 36136 futex_ S+   pts/1      0:00 /home/jwatte/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam
```

strace on 37591 shows that it's waiting on a futex, but nothing more:

```
[18:26] jwatte@ripper:~/Downloads$ sudo strace -p 37591
strace: Process 37591 attached
strace: [ Process PID=37591 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
futex(0x57df13c4, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, NULL
```

Using nvidia 384 drivers. (This has worked fine until now, so something must have changed, perhaps with the latest system update?)

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, re-installing from the dpkg didn't fix it.
However, re-booting my computer (which is annoying to do because it talks to a bunch of other things in the background) did "fix" the problem.
What is this, Windows ME? :-(